# nicescroll plugin - unable to copy contents other then in view port on scroll down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, scrollbar

I am using the jquery scroll plugin : nicescroll - http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html

I have a div attached with the nicescroll, the contents in the div are large say 100 lines but I am only displaying 10 lines at a time. The scrolling is working perfectly but I am unable to copy the contents more then 10 visible lines as scrollbar doesn't scroll down when my mouse has reached the end of the 10th line. This behaviour of scrolling down when we copy data is normal and standard but unable to perform so using the plugin. I have gone through the complete documentation and was unable to find the solution, so posting here.
I have observed the same issue on their site.

Does anyone have any solution to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement for the copy content on the scroll has been implemented in the plugin in the latest version v.3.2.0. The new option added to the plugin is enablescrollonselection.

Thanks InuYaksa. You can download the latest version from https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll